# Django incremental User Number if matching previous x letters

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a model for the user which includes first_name, last_name, company_name, reference_id etc. Now, I would like to create a referece_id based on the inputs of those other attribrutes. ie first 3 consonants of the last name, first 3 letters of the first name and then an incremental 3 digit number starting with 001. If any of the names have less than 3 letters the missing letters are replaced with an 'X'. The part I am struggling with is the 3 digits. The idea is that if the combination of the first 6 is unique then the digits are 001. Then the next user to match those same 6 digits is 002 and so forth. A full reference_id is like this: MDVTAS001 for example.

Any ideas how I can handle the look up to ensure incrementing numbers for the matching users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using a model lookup with first 6 letters, counting the number of results. incrementing by 1 and using zfill to fill the missing number of digits. Like  below:

```
first_name_tres = first_name.lower()[0:3].ljust(3,'x')
print("first name 3: " + first_name_tres)
last_name_tres = last_name.lower().translate({ord(i): None for i in 'aeiou'})[0:3].ljust(3,'x')
print("last name 3: " + last_name_tres)
user_ref_count =  str(ProfileMember.objects.filter(reference_id__contains=(last_name_tres + first_name_tres)).count()+1).zfill(3)
print("user ref count: " + user_ref_count)
reference_id = last_name_tres + first_name_tres + user_ref_count
```